# Automatic deletion of anonymous Firebase accounts

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I use Firebase Database and Storage to host some pictures for my Android app. Those pictures are only uploaded by me from the Firebase web interface. The Database and Storage have rules so only authenticated users can read and nobody is allowed to write. (So there is NO user generated content, I just need a place to host graphics for my Android app).

The reason authentication is required for read access is to make sure nobody else uses the pictures in another app (or website). For the authentication I create (only) anonymous accounts. (They are created automatically on first app start).

My question is about the anonymous user accounts: Will these ever be deleted when they aren't used anymore? Every time I clear data (or reinstall) my app, then another anonymous user account is created.

Is this something I should worry about or is this normal behaviour? Is there anything I could improve in my situation? Please note that this part of my app is not yet live for all users, so I can change stuff if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication does not automatically delete accounts.

But no data is maintained on the server for anonymous accounts, so effectively every time your users lose their anonymous authentication token, that account is forgotten by Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So does this mean this is the correct way to host some graphics for an Android app? And it doesn't matter that all the (unused) accounts are still in the list? (Firebase > Authentication)

Comment: I tried to answer the most concrete question from your post. But recommending a specific technology over another is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I guess I'll just leave all the anonymous accounts, and just not worry about it. Btw: are you aware that Firebase Storage broke in the latest update? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036495/firebase-storage-10-2-6-could-not-open-resulting-stream

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Functions for Firebase along with some scheduling mechanism to periodically delete unused accounts.  There is sample code [on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good to know that this is an option, too. However, for now I'll just leave the accounts as it shouldn't cause any problems. Edit: One more thing, does the "last sign in" also include all the automatic sign-ins on Android? Just wondering because Firebase console does not update the "Signed In" date for me. Is this normal? Let me know if you want a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a different question that you should tag with firebase-authentication.